# Rcplex error - is not a valid package

Tags: r, optimization, installation, cplex

I am using R 3.1.3 and had installed Rcplex via tar.gz file at http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcplex/index.html

When I load the library I get following error:

```
library (Rcplex)
Error in library(Rcplex) : ‘Rcplex’ is not a valid installed package
```

EDIT:

The package was installed by extracting the contents of the tar.gz file where other libraries are stored /installed.

Also tried installing it through the source:

```
install.packages ("<file path>/Rcplex_0.3-2.tar.gz", repos=NULL,type="source")

In install.packages("("<file path>//Rcplex_0.3-2.tar.gz",: installation of package ‘("<file path>/Rcplex_0.3-2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Lastly, tried via CRAN url.

```
install.packages ("Rcplex", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org",type="source")
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib
Warning message: package ‘Rcplex’ is not available (for R version 3.1.3)
```

Comment: can you try `ls("package:Rcplex")`?

Comment: ls ("package:Rcplex")
    Error in as.environment(pos) : 
  no item called "package:Rcplex" on the search list

Comment: Please update your question with your installation process. Also, check your .\Documents\R\win-library\3.3 folder

Comment: You might want to look in the DESCRIPTION file of your extracted Rcplex package and install the version of R specified there. Then you should install Rcplex using that version of R, probably from source (using your `.tar.gz` file as the source and `repos = NULL`).